# PHP ZipArchive is crashing after zipping a lot of files

Tags: php, laravel-8, ubuntu-20.04, php-ziparchive

I've created a simple programe that put photos into ZipArchive. All is working till I try to compress more than a couple photos (about 60). And after than I have something like that on a screen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtgHG.png

I've changed max_execution_time to 1200 and memory_limit to 256M in php.ini.

*Server is on Nginx 1.18 with PHP7.4 and Ubuntu 20.4. All is working on Laravel 8.*

Any ideas?

This is my ZipController

```
public function downloadZip(Request $req){   

    $id = $req->input('id');

    $sessions = DB::table('sessions')->where('id', $id)->get();
    $photos = DB::table('sessions_files')->where('session_id', $id)->get();

    $zip = new ZipArchive;

    $path = 'images/sessions/'.$id;

    $fileName = 'Sesja-numer-'.$id.'.zip';

    if ($zip->open($fileName, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
    {
        $numerek = 1;
        foreach ($photos as $photo) {
            echo $photo->file;
            $addFile = $path.'/'.$photo->file;
            $fileNewName = 'Zdjecie-'.$numerek.'.jpg';
            $zip->addFile($addFile, $fileNewName);
            $numerek++;
        }
        ob_end_clean();
        $zip->close();            
    }
    
    return response()->download($fileName)->deleteFileAfterSend();
    return redirect('/dashboard/sessions/'.$id);

}
```

Comment: That looks like what happens when you open a zip file in a text editor. Or display a zip file on screen.

Comment: Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: Scroll all the way to the bottom and see if there's an error message (make sure visible errors are enabled) or see the error logs. Always check for errors first.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have had that before, it happens when you add a file to the ziparchive, and that file doesn't exist or is not readable due to file permissions. Best to check file_exists() before adding it to the archive. The zip archive doesn't hit the error until you close, and it try's to read all the files at that point